# Launching new Intents with SingleInstance

Tags: android, twitter, android-activity, android-intent

I have two activities. One activity has the main game and the other activity has the game over screen which is truly just a custom alert dialog. In the game over screen there is a button that when clicked launches a new Activity.

```
String authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(httpOauthConsumer, OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));             
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY );
            startActivity(intent);
```

The page is a twitter authorization page but the problem I am having is that when I click the Authorize App button the activity with the alert dialog launches again (Calling create instead of onNewIntent).

I have tried different launch modes (singleInstance,singleTask and singleTop).

Each of them have their problems. singleInstance and singleTask will clear the original calling activity so when the AlertDialog slides in the original activity is changed to the menu page. singleTop always calls create again first (eventhough it doesn't call onDestroy)

Does anyone have any recommendations or examples on how I can get this done?

Incidentally, the activity that calls the game activity is a standard launchmode

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try `singleTask` + `taskAffinity` ?(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) I'm not tried that, but by the document, that combination should work for your requirement.

Comment: Just gave it a try. I gave both activities the same affinityName (I suppose that what is being suggested) but it had the same reaction. With singleTask the calling Activity always gets wiped out of the stack.

Comment: @Wise one: "the other activity has the game over screen which is truly just a custom alert dialog." -- why? Why not just have a plain activity with no dialog? Or, why not just have a dialog-themed activity? Why have an activity that only exists to show a dialog? As a bonus, it should clear up your problem, since you won't have an alert dialog.

Comment: Even removing the dialog (I just tried your suggestion) still causes the calling activity to be removed from the stack when I use singleTask. Is there a way to ensure that nothing is removed from the stack or is that a requirement for singleTask and singleInstance?

Comment: No. I'm using singleTask in my app and it works well. It doesn't interrupt base task(task of calling activity) and create another task as document said. I guess that when you tried singleTask, no other task generated. check task id by using Activity's `getTaskId()`. If caller and callee have same id, new task is not created and that's not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was make the call to the the new activity from the original caller. So when I choose to  to tweet the message from the custom alert dialog I close the alert dialog activity with the result requesting a tweet and from the original activity I make the call to the third activity (twitter authorization). It's not the answer I was looking for but this is how I solved the problem. If anyone knows a better more eloquent solution I'd love to know it.

SO The flow now goes A->B->A->C->A->B instead of A->B->C->B